# Specify Beam Version for Dataflow Operator on Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

We have written a Beam pipeline for version 2.11 but when we try to run it on Cloud Composer using the DataflowOperator it uses SDK version 2.5.

Is there anywhere to specify that 2.11 should be used?

Pipeline:

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp import gcsio
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import logging
from google.cloud import storage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

GCS_PREFIX = 'gs://'


def run(argv=None):
    """
    Create and run Dataflow pipeline.
    :return: none
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Add the arguments needed for this specific Dataflow job.
    parser.add_argument('--gvcf_bucket', dest='gvcf_bucket', required=True,


    parser.add_argument('--parquet_bucket', dest='parquet_bucket', required=True,
                        help='Bucket on Google Cloud Storage to write parquet files to.')

    parser.add_argument('--destination_table', dest='destination_table', required=True,
                        help='BigQuery table where transformed gvcfs should land')

    parser.add_argument('--bq_dataset', dest='bq_dataset', required=True,
                        help='BigQuery dataset where destination table lives')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # Add argument so that declared constants (ie, GCS_PREFIX)
    # are available to Dataflow workers
    pipeline_args.append('--save_main_session')

    # Set options necessary for pipeline such as runner, project, region
    p_opts = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    # Create and run beam pipeline object
    with beam.Pipeline(options=p_opts) as p:

        # Sink info
        gvcf_bucket = known_args.gvcf_bucket
        parquet_sink = known_args.parquet_bucket

        # Set BigQuery Table spec for beam.io
        # format is: dataset.table
        table_spec = '{}.{}'.format(known_args.bq_dataset, known_args.destination_table)

        # Get files to transform
        files = get_files_to_transform(gvcf_bucket)

        if files:

            logging.info("Found {} files to transform".format((len(files))))

            # Create pcollection of list of files to transform
            gvcfs_to_transform = p | 'GetFiles' >> beam.Create(files)

            # Read gvcfs from gcs into pcollection
            parquets_to_load = gvcfs_to_transform | 'GvcfToParquet' >> beam.ParDo(GvcfToParquet(),
                                                                                  gvcf_bucket,
                                                                                  parquet_sink)

            # Read Parquet files into pcollection
            records = parquets_to_load | 'ReadParquet' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromParquet()

            # Load all Parquet files into BigQuery
            records | 'WriteParquetToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table_spec,
                                                                           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)

        else:
            logging.info("No new files found")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Composer

```
import datetime
import os

from airflow import models, configuration
from airflow.operators import subdag_operator, dummy_operator, bash_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataflow_operator
import googleapiclient.discovery
import json
from computation_query_dag import computation_dag

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'retries': 0,
    'project_id': models.Variable.get('gcp_project'),
    'dataflow_default_options': {
        'project': models.Variable.get('gcp_project'),
        'temp_location': models.Variable.get('gcp_temp_location'),
        'staging_location': models.Variable.get('gcp_staging_location'),
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        # 'region': 'us-central1',
    },
}

with models.DAG(dag_id='TestEngine',
                description='',
                schedule_interval=None, default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS, start_date=yesterday) as dag:

    dataflow_scripts = os.path.join(configuration.get('core', 'dags_folder'), 'pipeline')

    # Args required for the ETL Dataflow job.
    gvcf_dataflow_job_args = {
        'gvcf_bucket': os.getenv('gvcf_bucket'),
        'parquet_bucket': os.getenv('parquet_bucket'),
        # 'job_name': os.getenv('gvcf_job_name'),
        #'setup_file': os.path.join(dataflow_scripts, 'setup.py'),
        'requirements_file': os.path.join(dataflow_scripts, 'requirements.txt'),
        'destination_table': os.getenv('call_table'),
        'bq_dataset': os.getenv('bq_dataset'),
        # 'py_file': os.path.join(dataflow_scripts, 'gvcf_pipeline.py')
    }

    # Dataflow task that will process and load.
    dataflow_gvcf = dataflow_operator.DataFlowPythonOperator(
        task_id="gvcf-etl-bigquery",
        py_file=os.path.join(dataflow_scripts, 'gvcf_pipeline.py'),
        # dataflow_default_options=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS['dataflow_default_options'],
        options=gvcf_dataflow_job_args,
        # gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default'
    )
```

Since I am able to run the pipeline locally I would think that if we specified the Beam version it would work when run from Cloud Composer also.

We have installed 2.11 into our Composer environment but we get the following error:

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://us-central1-test-env-96162c22-bucket/logs/AlleleAnalyticsEngine/gvcf-etl-bigquery/2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00/1.log.
[2019-04-17 22:33:18,604] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Engine.gvcf-etl-bigquery 2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-04-17 22:33:18,611] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Engine.gvcf-etl-bigquery 2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-04-17 22:33:18,613] {models.py:1573} INFO -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-04-17 22:33:18,659] {models.py:1595} INFO - Executing <Task(DataFlowPythonOperator): gvcf-etl-bigquery> on 2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00
[2019-04-17 22:33:18,660] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', u'airflow run Engine gvcf-etl-bigquery 2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00 --job_id 209 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/main_dag.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpGhGCxD']
[2019-04-17 22:33:20,148] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:20,147] {settings.py:176} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,073] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,072] {default_celery.py:80} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,076] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,075] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,155] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,155] {app.py:51} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,162] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,162] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,174] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,174] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-04-17 22:33:21,363] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:21,362] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/main_dag.py
[2019-04-17 22:33:23,991] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:23,985] {cli.py:484} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: AlleleAnalyticsEngine.gvcf-etl-bigquery 2019-04-17T22:33:07.326577+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-796dcd49fc-x7fx6
[2019-04-17 22:33:24,237] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:24,236] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:120} INFO - Running command: python2 /home/airflow/gcs/dags/pipeline/gvcf_pipeline.py --runner=DataflowRunner --parquet_bucket=parquet_sink_test --runner=DataflowRunner --region=us-central1 --labels=airflow-version=v1-10-1-composer --destination_table=calls_table_test --project=genomics-207320 --bq_dataset=allele_analytics --gvcf_bucket=gvcf_sink_test --temp_location=gs://aa_dataflow_staging/temp --job_name=gvcf-etl-bigquery-cfc96be4
[2019-04-17 22:33:25,214] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:25,213] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:151} INFO - Start waiting for DataFlow process to complete.
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,821] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:43,820] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:132} WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/pipeline/gvcf_pipeline.py", line 339, in <module>
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,822] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     run()
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,823] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/pipeline/gvcf_pipeline.py", line 335, in run
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,823] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     logging.info("No new files found")
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,824] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 426, in __exit__
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,825] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self.run().wait_until_finish()
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,825] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 406, in run
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,825] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self._options).run(False)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,827] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 419, in run
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,831] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,831] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 408, in run_pipeline
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,831] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self.dataflow_client = apiclient.DataflowApplicationClient(options)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,832] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 445, in __init__
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,835] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     response_encoding=get_response_encoding())
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,835] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py", line 58, in __init__
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,835] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     response_encoding=response_encoding)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,835] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'response_encoding'
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,832] {models.py:1760} ERROR - DataFlow failed with return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 332, in execut
    self.py_file, self.py_options
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 241, in start_python_dataflo
    label_formatter
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 213, in wrappe
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 199, in _start_dataflo
    job_id = _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done(
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 172, in wait_for_don
    self._proc.returncode)
Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,840] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:43,832] {models.py:1760} ERROR - DataFlow failed with return code 1
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,841] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,841] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,841] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,841] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 332, in execute
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,841] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self.py_file, self.py_options)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,843] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 241, in start_python_dataflow
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,843] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     label_formatter)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,843] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 213, in wrapper
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,844] {models.py:1791} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,844] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,845] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 199, in _start_dataflow
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,845] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     job_id = _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done()
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 172, in wait_for_done
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self._proc.returncode))
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 1
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,848] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery [2019-04-17 22:33:43,844] {models.py:1791} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,890] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,891] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,891] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,892] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,892] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     args.func(args)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,893] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,893] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,893] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 490, in run
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,894] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,894] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 406, in _run
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,895] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     pool=args.pool,
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,895] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,895] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,897] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,897] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,897] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 332, in execute
[2019-04-17 22:33:43,899] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self.py_file, self.py_options)
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,083] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 241, in start_python_dataflow
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,083] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     label_formatter)
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,083] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 213, in wrapper
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,084] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,084] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 199, in _start_dataflow
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,084] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     job_id = _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done()
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,085] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 172, in wait_for_done
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,085] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery     self._proc.returncode))
[2019-04-17 22:33:44,085] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 209: Subtask gvcf-etl-bigquery Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 1
```

Comment: You might want to ask in Apache Airflow's dev email channel, which you can find in https://airflow.apache.org/project.html.

Cloud composer is backed by Apache Airflow.

Comment: Thanks @RuiWang. This ended up being a dependency issue with Beam needing `google-apitools==0.5.26` which isn't installed in the Airflow workers.

Comment: Could you post what you did as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `google-apitools==0.5.26` to the Composer environment using the PyPi Packages option.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, I am facing the same issue... I add the `google-apitools==0.5.26` to the Composer environment but still no changes! 
Any suggestions on the steps you followed?

Answer (score 0):

Check your composer image version and see if it has the pypi package for apache-beam version you want.
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unclear answer!